# Зациклить определение високосного года

Tags: python, while

Программа определяет какой год високосный.

User вводит значение, получает ответ, потом первичный вопрос должен циклироваться: "Which year?: ".

Не могу зациклить его, подскажите, что Я делаю не так?

---

```
year = int(input("Which year?: "))

while True:
   if year % 4 != 0 or (year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 != 0):
      print("usual year")
   else:
      print("intercalary year")
      break
```

Comment: Ну так поместите его внутрь цикла. В чём затруднения?

Comment: @andreymal не очень Вас понял, что Вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Очевидно, чтобы зациклить что-то, это что-то должно быть внутри цикла. Если вы хотите зациклить вопрос, поместите его внутри цикла. Какие проблемы?

Comment: @andreymal Вы гений!!!!! Спасибо!

Comment: _Високосный год_ - leap year. _Intercalary year_ в наше время не существует и вряд ли вообще когда был в истории человечества. Но зато есть intercalary day, это день, который вставляется, чтобы выровнять календарь. 29 февраля. [Читать далее](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercalation_%28timekeeping%29).

Comment: @Эникейщик спасибо за инфо!

Comment: хе-хе, хотел написать комментарий по поводу _intercalary year_ и _leap year_, но увидел, что я его уже написал два года назад :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while True:
   year = int(input("Which year?: "))
   if year % 4 != 0 or (year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 != 0):
      print("usual year")
   else:
      print("intercalary year")
      break
```